# What is the meaning of "lay nestled" in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "lay nestled" in the following sentence,

> Glazed with barbecue sauce, the rack of ribs **lay nestled** next to a
>   pile of sweet coleslaw.

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Nestled" means that something is lying or sitting comfortably within or against something. It is derived from the word "nest", like a baby bird's nest, and often it is used to describe a baby's snug position such as being cradled close to its mother. Its broader meaning can be applied to anything that fits comfortably next to or within something.

In your example, it is a good use of the broader meaning as it is describing a plate of good food and "nestled" gives the sense that it is well-arranged on the plate and "fits" together well.